# Matlab Array has strange syntax

Tags: matlab, cell-array

In Matlab, we use textscan to get a cell array from a file or somewhere. But the behavior of the cell array is so strange.
There is the sample code:

```
>> str = '0.41 8.24 3.57 6.24 9.27';
>> C = textscan(str, '%3.1f %*1d');
>> C

C = 

[5x1 double]
```

We can know that C is a cell array of size 5 * 1. When I use C{1}, C{1}{1} and C(1). I get the following result:

```
>> C{1}

ans =

0.4000
8.2000
3.5000
6.2000
9.2000

>> C{1}{1}
Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.

>> C(1)

ans = 

[5x1 double]
```

Why I cannot use C{1}{1} to get the element from the cell array ? Then how can I get the elements from that cell array ?

An example I found on the Internet is :

```
%% First import the words from the text file into a cell array
fid = fopen(filename);

words = textscan(fid, '%s');

%% Get rid of all the characters that are not letters or numbers
for i=1:numel(words{1,1})
    ind = find(isstrprop(words{1,1}{i,1}, 'alphanum') == 0);
    words{1,1}{i,1}(ind)=[];
end
```

As words{1,1}{i,1}(ind)=[] show, what is the mechanism of using {}?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a slightly different syntax for indexing into cell arrays and numerical arrays.  Your output

```
>> C
C = 

[5x1 double]
```

is telling you that what you have is a 1x1 cell array, and in that 1 cell is a 5x1 array of doubles.  Cell arrays are indexed into with `{}`, while 'normal' arrays are indexed into with `()`.

So you want to index into the first element of the cell array, and then index down to the first value in the 5x1 array of doubles using `C{1}(1)`.  To get the second value - `C{1}(2)`, and so forth.

If you're familiar with other programming languages, cell arrays are something like arrays of pointers; the operator `A(n)` is used to get the nth element of the array A, while `A{n}` gets the object pointed to by the nth element of the array A (or 'contained in the nth cell of cell array A'). If A is not a cell array, `A{n}` fails.

So, knowing that C is a cell array, here's why you got what you got in the cases you tried -

`C{1}` returns the 5x1 double array contained in the first cell of C.

`C{1}{1}` gets the object (call it B) contained in the first cell of C, and then tried to get the object contained in the first cell of B.  It fails because B is not a cell array, it is a 5x1 double array.

And `C(1)` returns the first element of `C`, which is a single cell containing a 5x1 double array.

But `C{1}(1)` would get you the first element of the 5x1 array contained in the first cell of `C`, which is what you are looking for.  As @Cheery above me noted, it's probably easier, instead of writing `C{1}(1)`, `C{1}(2)`, ... to remove the 'cell-level' indexing by setting C=C{1}, which means `C` is now a 5x1 double array, and you can get the elements of it using `C(1)`, `C(2)`, ...  Hope that makes sense!

Comment: The detailed explanation makes me get the underlying reasons for this cell array. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> Then how can I get the elements from that cell array ?

```
C = C{:}; % or C = C{1};
```

Access values by `C(1)`, `C(2)` and so on